# Триггер Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

У меня есть две связанные таблицы: **журнал операций** и **номенклатура расходников**. Во второй таблице всего 5 расходников (их ID - порядковый номер).

Мне надо написать триггер на добавление данных в таблицу **журнал операций**, такой, чтобы он срабатывал, если ID расходника нет в таблице **номенклатура расходников**.

Делаю так, но срабатывает он всегда, что не так?
Примерно такую реализацию я видел на сайте Майкрософт.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER9
ON  [dbo].[Журнал операций]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN    ​    
    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].[Журнал операций] AS op
        JOIN ​inserted AS i
            ON op.[id расходника] = i.[id расходника]
        JOIN [dbo].[Номенклатура материалов] AS m
            ON m.[id расходника] = op.[id расходника]
        WHERE m.[id расходника] > 5)
​
    ​BEGIN
        ​​RAISERROR ('NET RASXODNIKA', 16, 1);
        ​​ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        ​​RETURN
    ​END;
END
GO
```

Comment: Приведи примеры когда работает, а когда нет ? Попробуй проверить текущий id записи, для которой произошло обновление через @@IDENTITY.

Comment: @faksel была опечатка, он всегда срабатывает. Т.е. когда я ввожу номер расходника который есть в таблице, триггер все равно срабатывает и лезет ошибка

Comment: m.[id расходника] > 5  из-за этого условия

Comment: Попробуйте for insert вместо instead of insert.

Comment: @faksel можете в ответах это написать, поставлю галку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m.[id расходника] > 5 из-за этого условия